# Reusing directive functions in another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a `dropdownToggle` directive and it has functions like:

```
toggle()
isOpen()
open()
close()
closeAll()
```

They all work perfectly except now I have a little problem. I need to call the `closeAll()` function from another directive.

The reason is my main content area has a `click` event listener attached which needs to close all currently open dropdown panels/menus.

How can this be achieved? I was thinking of moving all those functions into a `service` but I'd prefer to keep DOM manipulation in directives if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typical case where you need one directive to *augment another directive's behavior*.
According to **[the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile#-controller-)**, the controller property of the Directive Definition Object is what you need:

> **controller**
>   Controller constructor function. The controller is instantiated before the pre-linking phase and it is shared with other directives (see require attribute). This allows the directives to communicate with each other and augment each other's behavior. The controller is injectable (and supports bracket notation) with the following locals:
>
> - $scope - Current scope associated with the element
> - $element - Current element
> - $attrs - Current attributes object for the element
> - $transclude - A transclude linking function pre-bound to the correct transclusion scope. The scope can be overridden by an optional first argument. function([scope], cloneLinkingFn).

---

In order to get access to the controller of the first directive you need to `require` it from the second:

```
.directive('directive1', function () {
    return {
        ...
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            this.doSomething = function () {
                alert('Directive1: Done something !');
            };
        },
        ...
    };
});

.directive('directive2', function () {
    return {
        ...
        require: 'directive1',
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs, dir1Ctrl) {
            scope.doSomething = dir1Ctrl.doSomething;
        }
    };
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/DMeA7/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your functions in the directive's controller, and then require it from another directive. Another way would be to `emit` or `broadcast` custom event, on which you would listen in the destination controller.

If you don't know them, check the tutorials at [egghead.io](http://www.egghead.io/), they have been enlightening for me. In particular, this one addresses exactly your issue:

[egghead.io - Directive communication](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-directive-communication)

Answer (score 0):

The service is an option, it does *not* have to do DOM manipulation. The instances of the directive (or any other directive interested to take part in this behaviour) could register themselves in the service to be notified. The service itself would only perform the notification part.

If it is only notifications, it can be done with an event on the `$rootScope`, i.e. using `$rootScope.$on()` and `$rootScope.$emit()` for this purpose.

In any case, do not forget to unregister the listener on `$destroy`: `$scope.$on("$destroy", function() { /*unregister listener here*/ })` (hint: `scope.$on()` returns the deregistration function).

Comment: You don't need to emit/broadcast from the rootScope, since directives have access to a scope as well.

Comment: The directives may - in the general case - be place anywhere in the hierarchy. Their scopes may be siblings, in which case `$emit`-ing/`$broadcast`-ing will not transfer the event. `emit`-ing on the `$rootScope` achieves 2 things: They all get the message, since there is only one `$rootScope` and there is the minimum number of scopes involved, hopefully minimizing performance penalties (`$emit`-ing/`$broadcast`-ing in any other, inner scope will affect either its parents or its children as well; the `$rootScope` has no parents to forward the `$emit`-ed event, so it stays there).

Comment: You are right, I didn't think about the siblings case.